# Google Pie Chart div margin

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to remove a margin from a div created by google charts without any luck.
I have no margins set on my code that this div may inherit.

Bellow there is an image of the div.

[div unknown margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCCIG.png)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are asking is to remove the margin so that it is closer to the other divs. If that is the case then you could do this in a `<style></style>`

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Note that this will make every div and everything closer

If you didn't mean move it closer but move it into the center then you could do this.

```
<style>
    .your-div-class {
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I hope that answered your question, if it didn't then could you tell me what you meant by removing the margin because I am not fully sure what you meant by it.

Comment: the body already has the margin and padding set to 0 and margin auto didn't work. My problem is the div created by google charts. the one that is highlighted on the inspect panel on the right. that margin is nowhere on the code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem.
it's a margin google charts places to fill the unused area if overall dimensions and chartarea are not properly set.